# WIth terraform, adding encrypted non-root volume in a launch template fails on plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

This works:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "instances" {
...

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name           = "/dev/xvdb"
    ebs {
      volume_type           = "gp2"
      volume_size           = 250
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }
```

But, when I try to add in this:

```
block_device_mappings {
  device_name           = "/dev/xvdb"
  ebs {
    volume_type           = "gp2"
    volume_size           = 250
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted             = true
    kms_key_id            = "${data.aws_kms_key.instances.id}"
  }
}
```

So, I can't add the encryption pieces.  The key exists, is enabled, and has permissions for accessing it.  When i remove the encryption lines, plan runs to completion and so evidently it would apply.

terraform plan shows this:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.asg_instances.aws_autoscaling_group.instances_asg: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.asg_instances.aws_autoscaling_group.instances_asg: Resource 'aws_launch_template.instances_lt' not found for variable 'aws_launch_template.instances_lt.id'
```

The code for the asg is:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "instances_asg" {
  max_size                  = 5
  min_size                  = 2
  min_elb_capacity          = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  health_check_type         = "ELB"
  desired_capacity          = 3
  force_delete              = false
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.instances_subnets.*.id}"]
  load_balancers            = ["${aws_elb.instances_elb.name}"]

  launch_template {
    id      = "${aws_launch_template.instances_lt.id}"
    version = "$$Latest"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Evidently, the launch template doesn't even get created when i have the encryption lines causing the reference to it in the ASG to fail.  It doesn't error out on the launch template not even getting created, which it should.

Intention is to create an ASG based on this launch template which creates instances with an encrypted non-root volume

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Your `aws_launch_template` is named `instances` and not `instances_lt`.

Comment: ah, well, i changed all of the resource names and references just for obscurity.  I realize now that runs the risk of confusing the issue if I make a typo on the renames.  In the un-obscured code, i verifed the reference in asg to the launch template AND the resource name for aws_launch_template are the same.  With only the change of the two encryption lines in block_device_mappings, it either works or doesn't work.  Details were obscured due to security request (hyper-sensitive much I suppose?). Thanks for your help and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that we can run to see this behaviour?

Comment: You need the AutoScaling Service role when using encrypted volumes. And the role needs access to the encryption KMS key.

Comment: @victorm, I verified that the AutoScaling Service role exists in IAM (I assume that satisfies the "you need") and I configured it to have access permissions to the KMS key (wasn't there).  Still, terraform fails on a plan with same error.  Do I need to reference the AutoScaling Service role in terraform somewhere?  I have looked and don't see it as an argument for either asg or launch_template resources.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I thought at first that should be no big deal after reading the content at the link, but I'm not entirely sure I can do that.  I've used so many data element calls in lieu of vars that the code expects specific components to exist already (like the kms key, for example).

Comment: @MikeRyan Go to the console and look the auto scaling group, and look the messages as to why it is not launching instances. Anyway, you KMS Key include the following entry in the policy: {
  "Sid": "Allow use of the key",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      “${service_linked_role}"
    ]
  },
  "Action": [
    "kms:Encrypt",
    "kms:Decrypt",
    "kms:ReEncrypt*",
    "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
    "kms:DescribeKey"
  ],
  "Resource": "*"
} ---

Comment: you can also create the role: resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "AWSServiceRoleForASG" {
  aws_service_name = "autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
}

Answer (score 1):

How can two people write similar code and make the same mistake? LOL

I came across this post and I had very similar code. I managed to debug and fix it. The problem is that this code is wrong.

> Blockquote

```
kms_key_id            = "${data.aws_kms_key.instances.id}"
```

It should be :

> Blockquote

```
kms_key_id            = "${data.aws_kms_key.instances.arn}"
```

It may come in handy for someone else. Hence, posting it.